# I cannot delete a user

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, blazor, crud

I am working CRUD app in Blazor and I got an error when doing the delete user function. I tried many ways but failed. Here is the code in my 3 files.

DAO.cs

```
public void DeleteUser(List<int> userIds)
        {
            string deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM Users WHERE UserID IN (@userIds)";
            Dictionary<string, object> delParams = new Dictionary<string, object> {
                { "@userIds", userIds } 
            };
            sqlManager.ExecuteNonQuery(deleteQuery, delParams);
        }
```

Service.cs

```
public void DeleteUsers(List<int> userIds)
        {
            dao.DeleteUser(userIds);
        }
```

User.razor

```
private List<Users> selectedUsers = new List<Users>();

    private async Task DeleteUser()
    {
        List<int> userIds = selectedUsers.Select(u => u.UserID).ToList();
        service.DeleteUsers(userIds);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/User", forceLoad: true);
    }
```

I cannot delete user and this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK6Df.png)

How to fix this error

Comment: When you asked your question, you were told *"Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)."* Please follow the instructions when posting your questions, as otherwise you are likely to receive down and/or close votes; meaning your question is far less likely to be answered.

Comment: If you're using Dapper, I believe the syntax for IN expansion to a list of IDs is to *not* place parentheses around your list i.e. Dapper expects `Execute("DELETE FROM x WHERE id IN @listOfIds", new{ @listOfIds = your_list_here } )`. If you're not using dapper, either use it, or expand those IDs manually into a list of parameters, or use a temp table, or..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify this

In Service.cs

```
public void DeleteUsers(params int[] userIds)
{
    dao.DeleteUser(userIds);
}
```

with this change, you pass the userIds list to the DAO layer. You need to pass it as a parameter array rather than a list.

In DAO.cs:

```
public void DeleteUser(params int[] userIds)
{
    string deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM Users WHERE UserID IN (" + string.Join(",", userIds) + ")";
    sqlManager.ExecuteNonQuery(deleteQuery);
}
```

You have to change the way how do the sql query for allow multiple params

In the method private async Task DeleteUser()
change how pass the param, Convert toList

```
service.DeleteUsers(userIds.ToArray())
```